# How to Save GridView Cell Values to Access Database in winforms DevExpress?

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress

Am new to Dev Express, I add GridView to Form and Attached Data source to the GridView. Now i perform some calculation and Obtain Total Result. Now i have 5 rows in GridView. I want to save all rows in Access Database, How to complete my Task ?

Thanks in Advance.

Sri

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to execute the update (insert) command which will save the modifications to the underlying DataBase.  To learn how this can be done, please refer to the

[Posting Data to a Connected Database](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument1082)